# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repitan varios modal usado para editar con Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, modal, laravel-blade

Es problema que tengo es que utilizo un `modal` para editar los proyectos, entonces cuando tengo mas de 2 (proyectos), al inspeccionar código me doy cuenta que se repite el modal para cada proyecto, lo cual quisiera evitar y que se muestre solo el que voy a editar.

osea tener solo 1 `modal` y que cuando de clic al botón para abrir el `modal` me obtenga los valores de ese proyecto para así no se genere varias veces.

eso es posible?

**proyectos(BLADE):**

```
@foreach ($proyectos as $proyecto)
  <div class="card">
    <!-- NOMBRE PROYECTO -->
    <div class="card-header">
        <div>{{$proyecto->proy_nombre}}</div>
        <!-- Editar -->
        <div >
             <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditarProyecto{{$proyecto->proy_id}}" href=""><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- DESCRIPCION PROYECTO -->
    <div class="card-body">{{$proyecto->proy_descripcion}}</div>
</div>
@include('modal.modal_editar_proyecto')
@endforeach
```

**modal_editar_proyecto (BLADE) :**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditarProyecto{{$proyecto->proy_id }}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditarPryectoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          {{$proyecto->proy_nombre}}
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo crearía mi Modal fuera del loop, para que se arme una sola vez, luego le pasaría los datos las variables dat-* por ejemplo, data-target, sería solamente EditarProyecto, luego otro que seria data-idproyecto, y eso lo tomaría con javascript, quedaría algo así;

```
@foreach ($proyectos as $proyecto)
  <div class="card">
    <!-- NOMBRE PROYECTO -->
    <div class="card-header">
        <div>{{$proyecto->proy_nombre}}</div>
        <!-- Editar -->
        <div >
             <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditarProyecto" data-idproyecto="{{$proyecto->proy_id}}" data-nombre="{{$proyecto->proy_nombre}}" href=""><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- DESCRIPCION PROYECTO -->
    <div class="card-body">{{$proyecto->proy_descripcion}}</div>
</div>
@endforeach
@include('modal.modal_editar_proyecto')
```

Luego el Modal;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditarProyecto" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditarPryectoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="nom-proyecto">
                Nombre del proyecto
            </div>
            <div class="id-proyecto">
                ID del proyecto
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Y por último, lo manejo con Javascript;

```
$('#EditarProyecto').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var nombre = button.data('nombre');
        var idproyecto = button.data('idproyecto');
        var modal = $(this);
        
        modal.find('.nom-proyecto').text( nombre );
        modal.find('.id-proyecto').text('Modificar permiso ' + idproyecto );
        
    });
```

Quizás existan formas mas óptimas o elegantes de hacerlo, pero yo lo haría de esta forma.

Comment: no me funciona, solo me muestra el dato del ultimo elemento.

Comment: Podrías modificar tu ejemplo con los ultimos ajustes que realizaste, porque no hay forma que te muestre el ultimo elemento si conmi ejemplo lo cambias dinamicante con JS

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono y me olvide aprobar esta respuesta hace mucho.